# Send sound to concrete output channel in Unity3D

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, fmod

I would like to know how can I send sound to concrete output channel in Unity3D. I have 3 output channels (and three speakers connected to 5.1 audiocard) and I want to put unique mono sound to everyone and one common spatial stereo sound to all of them with center in 2nd channel. Can I do it without additional tools like FMOD or WWISE?

P.S. I'm using Unity3D 5.4.0 and I would like to use Unity Mixer in this project. Regular stereo WAV files are the sources of sound.

Comment: Can you tell us what did you research/try so far?

Comment: Sorry for delay, I used FMOD eventually, it works fine.